# Как сделать плавное появление лишнего текста?

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

Всем привет, В общем есть карточка, определенной высоты. Чтобы не смещалось все внутри применил к тексту  overflow: hidden; height: 55px;
НЕ могу понять как сделать плавное появление при наведении  transition: overflow 10s ease-in-out; не помогает.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
   .cardItem {
      width: 50%;
      height: 470px;
      margin: .5em;
      font-size: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      background-color: white;
      border: .3em solid #b4bcc3;
    }

      .cardDetail {
        padding: .3em .4em;
        height: 100%;
      }
    .cardDetail a {
      display: block;
    }
      .articul {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 55px;
      }
    .articul p {
      font-size: 1em;
      color: #0065bc;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .articul:hover{
      overflow: visible;
      transition: overflow 10s ease-in-out;
    }

      .imgDetail {
        padding-top: .5rem;
      }
    .imgDetail .img{
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding-top: 150px;
    }

      .price {
        padding-top: .5rem ;
      }
    .price p {
      padding: .25rem 0;
      text-align: center;
      &:first-of-type {
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      &:nth-child(2) {
        font-size: 2.1em;
        font-weight: 800;
        span {
          font-size: .7em;
          font-weight: 600;
        }
      }
    }

      .manufactured {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 0;
        padding-top:.5rem;
      }
    .manufacturedInfo {
      width: 50%;
      font-size: 1rem;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .manufacturedInfo p {
      font-size: .8em;
    }
    .manufacturedInfo  p:first-of-type {
      font-size: .8em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .logoManufactured {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0 auto;
      
    }
    .logoManufactured img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
      .ExistenceBtn {
        padding-top: .5rem;
      }
    .ExistenceBtn p {
      border: .1em solid #000000;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: .95em;
      padding: .65em 0;
    }
   
      .PocketBuyBtn {
        padding-top: .5rem ;
      }
    .PocketBuyBtn  p {
      border: .1em solid #7fcd00;
      background-color: #7fcd00;
      color: #000000;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      padding: .15em 0;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="cardItem">
                                    <div class="cardDetail">

                                        <div class="articul">
                                            <a href=""><p>SNRКомплект sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsd ремня ГРМ RA2105413 </p></a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="imgDetail">
                                            <a href="">
                                                <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/0_14a7fc_411c2622_XXL.jpg')"></div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="price">
                                            <p>Цена:</p>
                                            <p> 675 <span>грн. </span></p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="manufactured">
                                            <div class="manufacturedInfo">
                                                <p>Производитель:</p>
                                                <p>SNR</p>
                                                <p>(Франция)</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="logoManufactured">
                                                <a href="">
                                                    <img src="http://st8.gismeteo.ru/static/news/img/src/1742/0ce1895b.jpg" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="ExistenceBtn">
                                            <p>есть в наличии</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="PocketBuyBtn">
                                            <p>купить</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Свойство overflow нельзя анимировать, т.к. нельзя представить промежуточные значения между hidden и visible. Можно анимировать, например, высоту. Причем между двумя обозначенными значениями. Анимировать между `height: 50px` и `height: auto` в CSS не выйдет. А между `height: 50px` и `height: 100px` уже можно

Comment: я конечно догадался что анимировать нельзя. А подскажите может кто знает как карточку правильно верстать что бы я посмотрел сделал для себя выводы. Если можно конечно заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принцип такой

```js
const titles = document.querySelectorAll(".articul p");

for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
  titles[i].onmouseover = function () {
    if (this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight) {
      this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px"
    }
  };
  titles[i].onmouseleave = function () {
    this.style.height = ""
  }
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.cardItem {
  width: 250px;
  height: 470px;
  margin: .5em;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border: .3em solid #b4bcc3;
}

.cardDetail {
  padding: .3em .4em;
  height: 100%;
}
.cardDetail a {
  display: block;
}
.articul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 55px;
}
.articul p {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #0065bc;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  height: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .2s linear;
  background: #fff
}

.imgDetail {
  padding-top: .5rem;
}
.imgDetail .img{
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.price {
  padding-top: .5rem ;
}
.price p {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  &:first-of-type {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 2.1em;
    font-weight: 800;
    span {
      font-size: .7em;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
  }
}

  .manufactured {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    padding-top:.5rem;
  }
.manufacturedInfo {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.manufacturedInfo p {
  font-size: .8em;
}
.manufacturedInfo  p:first-of-type {
  font-size: .8em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.logoManufactured {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
.logoManufactured img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
  .ExistenceBtn {
    padding-top: .5rem;
  }
.ExistenceBtn p {
  border: .1em solid #000000;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .95em;
  padding: .65em 0;
}

  .PocketBuyBtn {
    padding-top: .5rem ;
  }
.PocketBuyBtn  p {
  border: .1em solid #7fcd00;
  background-color: #7fcd00;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: .15em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardItem">
  <div class="cardDetail">
    <div class="articul">
      <a href="">
        <p>SNRКомплект sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsd ремня ГРМ RA2105413 </p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgDetail">
      <a href="">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/0_14a7fc_411c2622_XXL.jpg')"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <p>Цена:</p>
      <p> 675 <span>грн. </span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="manufactured">
      <div class="manufacturedInfo">
        <p>Производитель:</p>
        <p>SNR</p>
        <p>(Франция)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="logoManufactured">
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://st8.gismeteo.ru/static/news/img/src/1742/0ce1895b.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ExistenceBtn">
      <p>есть в наличии</p>
    </div>
    <div class="PocketBuyBtn">
      <p>купить</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```